# 'cypress-promise' library is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I have tests in which i used the [**cypress-promise**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-promise) library. I have included promisify in that to wait until my commands are executed and give response.
in my file i have 3 it's block when i ran individually it executes properly but when i run all at once first it and second it's api's aborted when url changes or url updated and last one's test are executed properly.

```
 it("visit particular employee", async ()=>{
  cy.visit("/")
  const id = 12
  const updatedEmployeeData = await cy.uploadEmployeeData().promisify();
  cy.visit(`/all-employess/${updatedEmployeeData[id].employeeCode}`);
  cy.get('.input').type(updatedEmployeeData[id].name);
  
 })
 
 it("visit particular employee  2", async ()=>{
  cy.visit("/")
  const id = 13
  const updatedEmployeeData = await cy.uploadEmployeeData().promisify();
  cy.visit(`/all-employess/${updatedEmployeeData[id].employeeCode}`);
  cy.get('.input').type(updatedEmployeeData[id].name)
 })

 it("visit particular employee", async ()=>{
  cy.visit("/")
  const id = 14
  const updatedEmployeeData = await cy.uploadEmployeeData().promisify();
  cy.visit(`/all-employess/${updatedEmployeeData[id].employeeCode}`);
  cy.get('.input').type(updatedEmployeeData[id].name)
 })


 in first it and second it after cy.visit(`/all-employess/${updatedEmployeeData[id].employeeCode}`); it stops executing and in third it properly executes.
```

I don't understand with this approach;

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you could take an alternate approach without cypress-promisify

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.visit("/")
  cy.uploadEmployeeData().as('updatedEmployeeData')
})

it("visit particular employee", () => {
  cy.get('@updatedEmployeeData').then(updatedEmployeeData => {
    const id = 12
    cy.visit(`/all-employess/${updatedEmployeeData[id].employeeCode}`);
    cy.get('.input').type(updatedEmployeeData[id].name);
  })
})
 
it("visit particular employee  2", () => {
  cy.get('@updatedEmployeeData').then(updatedEmployeeData => {
    const id = 13
    cy.visit(`/all-employess/${updatedEmployeeData[id].employeeCode}`);
    cy.get('.input').type(updatedEmployeeData[id].name)
  })
})

it("visit particular employee", () => {
  cy.get('@updatedEmployeeData').then(updatedEmployeeData => {
    const id = 14
    cy.visit(`/all-employess/${updatedEmployeeData[id].employeeCode}`);
    cy.get('.input').type(updatedEmployeeData[id].name)
  })
})
```

Alternative to avoid nested then.
The trade-off is you must use `function()` syntax for every `it()`

```js
beforeEach(() => {   // can be before() instead of beforeEach() if data does not change
  cy.visit("/")
  cy.uploadEmployeeData().as('updatedEmployeeData')
  cy.uploadManagerData().as('updatedManagerData')
})

it("visit particular employee", function() {  // use function() form 
                                              // so that "this" is defined correctly
  const id = 12
  cy.visit(`/all-employess/${this.updatedEmployeeData[id].employeeCode}`);
  cy.get('.input').type(this.updatedEmployeeData[id].name);

  // also use this.updatedManagerData
})
```

Comment: yes, this is another way of doing it. 
i tried in this way cy.uploadEmployeeData().then(() => {}), but i want some clarify in this, if multiple .then blocks are present then it might leads to multiple chaining. That's what i fear.

Comment: What do you want clarity in?

Comment: If you change `it('...', () => {` to `it('...', function() {` you can use `this.updatedEmployeeData[id]` and avoid the initial then in each test (assuming that is what concerns you).

Comment: yeah that work fine, but if i have cy.uploadEmployeeData() and another one cy.uploadManagerData() then in this case it might have to call this in beforeEach right!.
then if needed another then block in first then block  
ex: .then(() => {
   .then(() => {
   /// code  
  })
})
@Fody

Comment: Yes broadly speaking you are correct. There's a big discussion on Cypress github about using `await` on commands vs nested then blocks, and some proposal to add enhancements for it, but a couple of years on it's still pending. I'll update the answer to show you the alternative syntax that avoids nested thens.

Answer (score 1):

As the library documented on its page (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-promise): Did you import and polyfill the cy commands?

> An alternative it to use the 'register' polyfill to add promisify method to all Cypress chains. This requires import 'cypress-promise/register' in your cypress/support/index file

If not try to use the library in the way it is documented there:
`await promisify(<your cypress cmd>)`:

```
import promisify from 'cypress-promise'
 
it('should run tests with async/await', async () => {
  const foo = await promisify(cy.wrap('foo'))
  expect(foo).to.equal('foo')
})
```

If you did so, I can't help further but it is currently not really possible to read that fact out of your question.

Comment: Thank you for your response, yes i tried this way but not worked.

Answer (score -1):

I found that this doesn't work in Github actions yet, but works locally.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31656923)